# Adding a wcf service in a PC having IIS doesn't show the service in my client application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

I wrote a wcf service and I am trying to use it from my application.
I succeed to deply it on another PC which has IIS installed.
I open a new virtual Directory and paste all the files including service.svc, web.config, APP_Data
I am able to right-click on the svc file, click Browse and get a window telling that the service is created.It also give me the path to test my service.

From my client application, I am trying to add the service using "Add Service reference", I am pasting the path I got from the Browse button:
http://[MyIP]/PrintService/Service1.svc?wsdl, then clicking on Go but I am getting a message:

```
There was an error downloading 'http://[MyIp]/PrintService/Service1.svc?wsdl/$metadata'.
Unable to connect to the remote server
```

Comment: Firewall may be blocking it.

Comment: It works, please add an answer so I can mark it as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For diagnostics purposes only, turn off your firewall momentarily. If that solves the problem then turn your firewall back on immediately again, go to your windows firewall advanced settings and create an **Inbound Rule** allowing your service/port number to get through.

Answer (score 0):

Using IP address for services isn't the right approach. you can add that spesific host name to your hosts file. Using computer name is the best for development environment. because you are getting different ip each time most of the networks. Or for just development if your loopback adapter is rightly configured you can use 127.0.0.1 but it is not the best practise.